# Way to hide variable value in html

Tags: html

Is there any way that we can hide variable value in html? I dont want user to see the values at any cost.

`<input id="defaulterrormessage" type="hidden" th:value="${errorMsg}"></input>`

The above code will only hide from web page but if you inspect then you can see the value.

Answer (score 1):

No. Use AJAX to pull values from the server as needed instead of storing them in the HTML (or CSS as generated content values or JS as variables, since all those can be discovered).

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information? What are you trying to accomplish? If this is a form and you are assigning values after a submit, I suggest a server side language like php or c#.

If you are doing something with these values on your current page you could also store your values in a session variable or cookie depending on what is needed.

Comment: Its like I want to get some values from spring controller hide it in the html page and submit that value again to the controller when click submit form.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

**1) Make the value accessible by the page, but stored outside the page**

*eg.*

- Stored in **HTML5 localStorage**, accessible via `localStorage.getItem(value);`
- Stored in an **external JSON file**, accessible via Ajax
- Stored in a **cookie**, accessible via cookie interrogation

*etc.*

---

**2) Hide the encoded value in plain sight. Decode using javascript**

*eg.*

- Encode the value as **ASCII**
- Encode the value as **Base64**

*etc.*